# c# Search String value for variations of an abbreviation

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I need to search a Text Box after user input to see if there are any Occurrences of a particular abbreviation.

As an example, I want to see if the user has input one of the following:-

```
".AB ", "AB." , " AB ", "/AB", ",AB"
```

What is the cleanest way of doing this please?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or WinForms or something else? Please explain your scenario a bit further.

Comment: Your searching for an exact match or any match inside a string?

Comment: Its a win app, I'm just looking at detecting the above abbreviation in the text box in those formats, its part of my error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use Regular Expressions:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(yourTextBox.Text, @"((\.|,|\s)AB(\.|,|\s)"))) {
    // do something
}
```

Choose a regex that matches the strings you want to detect.

Answer (score 3):

Using the LINQ [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357185) extension method:

```
var abbreviations = new [] { ".AB ", "AB." , " AB ", "/AB", ",AB" };

return abbreviations.Contains(myTextBox.Text);
```

If you want the search to be case insensitive:

```
return abbreviations.Contains(myTextBox.Text.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the Contains() method of String. Example:

```
string[] abbreviationsList = { ".AB ", "AB.", " AB ", "/AB", ",AB" };
        foreach (string abbreviations in abbreviationsList)
        {
            if (myTextBox.Text.Contains(abbreviations))
            {
                // Your code here
            }
        }
```

There are other ways to do that, of course, but my point is using Contains() in the Text of your TextBox.

Comment: @Oded I edited my answer to include an example of how it would work with a list of strings.

Comment: So why use `Contains`? Why not `Equals`?

Comment: Because    Contains search for a fragment of the string, while    Equals looks for exact match. For instance: If you have a string "Stack" and use    Contains("a") it would find it, but Equals would say that they are different strings.

Comment: I don't see that requirement in the question.

Comment: He is looking for occurrences of a particular abbreviations, not for a exact match. It's like check if there is any occurrence of "Ave." in an address. It's supposed to be followed by the name of the Avenue, not only the abbreviation. So I believe Contains would be most appropriate, if I understood well what is he looking for.